# How to return a string in a method in an ionic typescript file and assign to a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Cannot return a string to another method in ionic typescript file.
We want to eventually return the JSON.stringify(res) and assign this to the stringset. When this didn't work we tried testing by simply returning a string "hi". This simple return does not work.
We have tried returning any or string types, the ide does not like the string type.

Please help in determining how to return a string from the postCall method so it is retained by the stringset variable.

```
 navNextQuestion() {
  let stringset = this.postCall("A004");
  this.navCtrl.push('QuestionPage', {
      firstPassed: stringset,
      secondPassed: "it did pass"
  });
 }


 //Below passes variable to PHP file#
 public postCall(id:string): string {
 let data=JSON.stringify({answer_id:id, type:"answer"});
 this.http.post('http://localhost/retrieve-data.php',data)
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(res => {
 alert("success "+JSON.stringify(res));

 //parses JSON response into array (uncomment below when ready)
 //this.response = JSON.stringify(res);

 return "hi";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your post and eventually your map to that funktion to use the JSON Data you recieve in your post.

You can only access the response data inside of the subscribe and the map funktion.

**Update**

```
navNextQuestion() {
let stringset = this.postCall("A004").subscribe(stringset => {
this.navCtrl.push('QuestionPage', {
  firstPassed: stringset,
  secondPassed: "it did pass"
   });
 });
}

 //Below passes variable to PHP file#
 public postCall(id:string){
 let data=JSON.stringify({answer_id:id, type:"answer"});
 return this.http.post('http://localhost/retrieve-data.php',data)
   .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I edited the code to exactly replace yours.

Comment: should the return statement you posted be placed instead of return "hi";

Comment: the .subscribe is throwing an error saying it does not exist for type void

Comment: and another error stating that stringset is unused. Help please.

Comment: Updated the Code. Tell me If you need further help

Comment: I had to stringify my stringset on the firstPassed variable, but is fine and working now!!!

Comment: glad to help you!